# AJAX Toolkit 'unknown server control' Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I just installed Ajax Toolkit. The controls are available in my Toolbox, but when I insert them in a page, Visual Studio underlines them with the error message "unknown server tag".

I googled the problem and found several ideas :

- check if the DLL is in Bin folder
- check if ajaxToolKit tags prefix is registered in web.config and make sure I'm not using a different prefix in my pages
- check if the DLL is registered in the pages with <% @ Register ... %>

Unfortunately all of this is fine, but I still can't get the controls to work. Is something else missing ?

**EDIT :** My environment is ASP.Net 2.0, Ajax Extensions 1.0, Ajax Toolkit 1.0.20229, Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you might have the wrong .Net version of the Ajax toolkit installed. Check http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's not the problem. I'm using one of the configurations recommended on your link (ASP.net 2.0, Ajax Extensions 1.0, Ajax Toolkit 1.0, Visual Studio 2005)

Comment: And your project is .Net 2.0? If thats the case you must use this version: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121

Comment: Yes, the project is .Net 2.0, and the exact version of Ajax Toolkit is 1.0.20229, the one you linked

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug and a bogus message that keeps coming time to time with Ajax control toolkit. Sometimes closing the VS and restarting helps. If that does not help, try removing the control toolkit and re-referencing again.